# security.yml requires_channel seems to be ignored

Tags: symfony, https

The basic symfony installation with the Acme application, I have changed the /app/config/security.yml to force https for the login form:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/demo/secured/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Then when I request the login form: `http://localhost/app_dev.php/demo/secured/login` I don't get redirected to https. Would expect it to redirect to https according to the following documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html

Maybe I need to remove cache but requestion `http://localhost/app_dev.php/demo/secured/login?refresh=123` doesn't forward me to https either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question above doesn't show **all** of the access_control declarations, here's another possible explanation:

If the access_control declarations appear in this order ...

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

... and the url is http://foo.com/login, then RequestMatcher.matches() will stop searching for declarations after "^/", since preg_match reports that "^/" matches "^/login". The protocol used will then be **http**.

But if the declarations are reversed ...

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

... then RequestMatcher.matches() will stop searching for declarations after "^/login", and the protocol used will then be **https**.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need few days ago and I had to alter `routing.yml` file. This is how I resolved it:

<kbd>**routing.yml**</kbd>

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    schemes: [https]
```

Although, I did use `FOSUserBundle`, this should be applicable to any routing configuration....

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you saying that security.yml and the requires_channel simply don't work and the documentation that hits nr1 on google when searching for `symfony force https` doesn't work? I guess I can use the nr2 on google and change the router but was wondering why the security.yml didn't do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: To be frank, I also searched for similar criteria on Google and have found this solution first. Also, I see now that this method is also described at the bottom of document you linked to (separate hyperlink)

Comment: I see it works for `{ path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }` Requesting that page gives me 301 moved permanently. Guess it's one of those fun things that you'll figure out when working with Symfony for a while (if you're not jumping off a building before that).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this via annotations (ie):

```
@Route("/checkout", name="cart_checkout", schemes={"https"})
```